# Adicionar elemento em um ArrayList somente se ele não existir(Android)

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Estou a programar um app bluetooth no Android Studio. Eu tenho um arrayList e nele coloco dispositivos que foram descobertos numa conexão bluetooth. Acontece que, quando eu executo a tarefa de procurar novos dispositivos pela segunda, terceira ... vez ele adicionar o mesmo dispositivo sendo que ele já estava na lista.

Essa é a parte do codigo em questão:

```
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                 int i = 0;
                while(i < itens.size())
                {
                    Log.i("Script", "Elemento na lista: "+itens.get(i).getNome());
                    i++;
                }
                // Get the "RSSI" to get the signal strength as integer,
                // but should be displayed in "dBm" units
                Item dispositivo = new Item();
                dispositivo.setNome(device.getName());
                dispositivo.setMac(device.getAddress());
                if (!itens.contains(device.getName())) {
                    Log.i("Script ", "Dispositivo " +device.getName()+" não existe na lista, ele foi adicionado");
                    updateList(dispositivo);
                }
            }

            }
        };
```

Na primeira execução do metodo, entao surge no meu Log:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que, ele verificou que um dispositivo não existia na lista e o adicionou, depois pra o segundo dispositivo, como a lista já tinha um item ele foi mostrado(Elemento na Lista: Galaxy J2 Prime), verificou se ele existia, como não, foi adicionado a lista(Dispositivo Jir não existe na lista, ele foi adicionado). Até ai tudo bem!

Acontece que ao chamar pelo metodo uma segunda, terceira vez, ele sempre adiciona os mesmos elementos na lista:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode ser ver que agora a elementos repetidos na Lista, creio eu que o erro está na comparação, itens.contais(), mas não sei como resolver, alguma ajuda?

Comment: Qual o tipo da lista `itens` que você usa? É de `String`? O erro realmente está no `itens.contains()` que parece estar comparando dois objetos de tipos diferentes um `String` e outro que parece ser um `Item`.

Answer (score 2):

Se está readicionando quer dizer que tua lógica não faz somente uma procura por novos dispositivos e sim uma busca de todos que aparecerem. Podes aproveitar o código simplesmente limpando a lista antes do inicio do algoritmo.

Answer (score 1):

Isso  está acontecendo porque internamente o método contains() da classe ArrayList faz uso do método equals(),então você precisará implementar o método equals,caso precise utilizar o método contains em um Set também será necessário implementar o método hashcode.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(this.name,this.adress);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Item)) {
        return false;
    }
    Item other = (Item) obj;
    return Objects.equals(name, other.name) && Objects.equals(adress, other.adress);
}
```